# kill my session without administrative privelage?

Tags: session, oracle11g, kill

I have accidently executed a procedure and i want o kill the session.

I have tried almost all the options i can search so far for granting access and killing sessions. but each time a SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges error is displayed.

Just want to know if there is any possible way I can kill this session.

PS: I am working on a Development environment.